# Is there a hiatus in the word "aerial"?

Tags: pronunciation, diaeresis

My editor *informed* me that, if I use any diaeresis marks at all, then I must be consistent! I consistently use a diaeresis mark in coördinator and coöperation.

The periodical, Popular Educator (c 1890) had this to say:

> “The Diæresis:  [#] 77.  The diæresis shows that the letter over which it is placed is to be pronounced separately; as, Creätor, zoönomia, aërial … “

I agree with, zo-onomia; and I can understand, Cre-ator, but a-erial?

The Encarta Dictionary (c 2000) shows the pronunciation of (aerial) as áiree əl.

Is it just my accent, or is there a hiatus in aerial?

Comment: The Webster's [1892 International Dictionary](http://books.google.com/books?id=qL8WAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=webster+dictionary+international&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UBoxUf_NLpOL0QHO24GYCA&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA) clearly shows a hiatus in the word aerial. I believe the predominant pronunciation has changed since then.

Comment: if it were anywhere, why wouldn't it be over the final A to separate it from the I? Wouldn't placing it over the E indicate a new syllable (ending with 4 syllables)? I say it with 3 syllables (air/ee/schwa-l)

Comment: If you look up aërial in the 1892 Webster's International dictionary (linked in my above comment) it did then have four syllables: ay EE ri al (/eɪˈi.rɪ.əl/).

Comment: @Dan, because, unlike the "ea" in "Creator" (which looks like "greater") and the "oo" in "cooperation" (which looks like "cooper") the ending "ia" looks like it would form two syllables naturally, as in _radial, incendiary, affiliate, abbreviate, bias_ and _hiatus_. That's my guess.

Comment: makes sense but it turns the mark into a reflection on the anticipation of the reader and not the inherent value of the pronunciation.

Comment: I smell Norty...

Comment: If you want to talk to English speaking people in 1892, by all means insert a hiatus. If you're speaking colloquial English, don't be silly.

Comment: Are you using the diaeresis to explain how to pronounce these words in your text? Because if you are simply writing normal text you would not use a diaeresis at all in these words. Cooperative is often written as one word, or hyphenated -  see The Co-operative Bank.

Answer (score 2):

This may just be my Australian accent, but I would pronounce that word as: "Air-ree-(schwa)l".

I don't hear any hiatuses.

Comment: That's the way everybody else in the world pronounces it too, as far as I know. Dictionaries from 1892 show an archaic pronunciation with four syllables.

Answer (score 2):

The root *aer-* used to be pronounced with a hiatus, but this seems to have become mostly archaic. Peter Shor mentioned this in some comments with a link to the [Webster's 1892 International Dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=qL8WAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=webster%20dictionary%20international&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UBoxUf_NLpOL0QHO24GYCA&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=aerial&f=false), which shows the pronunciation of *aërial* as /eɪˈi.ri.əl/.

I don't know for sure why the pronunciation changed to have /ɛər/. Here's some speculation. It looks like in most words, the "a" was stressed and the "e" was unstressed: for example, the pronunciation for *aëroplane* is given as /ˈeɪ.ər.oʊ.pleɪn/~/ˈeɪ.ər.ə.pleɪn/. It's fairly easy for /eɪ.ər/ and /ɛər/ to interchange. We see this sort of variation in the words *prayer* and *mayor,* for example (although this is not quite the same situation; in these words the monosyllabic pronunciations are actually quite old and may be partly based on sound changes that occurred in French). If we look at other vowels, we can find similar examples of coalescence that definitely occurred in English, such as the pronunciation of *drawer* as /drɔːr/ and the pronunciation of *theory* as /ˈθɪəri/.

This type of "smoothing" change wouldn't normally affect a word like *aërial* where *aër-* was pronounced as /eɪˈi.r/ rather than as /ˈeɪ.ər/. The /eɪˈir/ pronunciation seems to have been replaced by analogy with words like *aeroplane* (where smoothed /ˈeɪ.ər/ was reinterpreted as a single syllable /ɛər/). It seems likely the pronunciation of the related noun *air* as /ɛər/ also influenced this development.

If we look at entries for [*aerial* in modern online dictionaries](http://www.onelook.com/?w=aerial&ls=a), we can see the pronunciation /eɪˈi.ri.əl/ is not quite dead: it's still listed by the *[American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=aerial), [Merriam-Webster's Online Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aerial),* and *[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/aerial)* (which is based on the *Random House Dictionary*). But it's clearly not the main pronunciation: all of these dictionaries list /ˈɛər.i.əl/ as the first pronunciation for the adjective and the only pronunciation for the noun, and in many other dictionaries this is the only pronunciation listed for both parts of speech.

Another word spelled with "ae" that "should" have hiatus, but that has developed an alternative pronunciation is *aeneous,* from Latin *aēneus/ahēneus.* The Oxford English dictionary indicates that it may be pronounced with hiatus between the *a* and *e,* in accordance with the etymology (UK /eɪˈiːnɪəs/, US /eɪˈiniəs/) or it may be pronounced as if the *ae* came from a Latin diphthong (UK /ˈiːnɪəs/, US /ˈiniəs/). [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aeneous) and the [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=aeneous) only mention the pronunciation with hiatus, and [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/aeneous) only mentions the spelling pronunciation with *ae* = /iː/.